# Parse.com - dashboard users, collaborators

Tags: parse-platform

could you advice me, how to manage Dashboard users and Collaborators users within parse.com please ? I am not able to find any way how to manage them

Many thanks in advance

Josef

Answer (score 1):

To manage your collaborators just open the parse dashboard, select the app you wish to manage the collaborators for, select the Settings icon (the cog) up the top of the browser window, then choose Collaborators on the left menu. There you can add and remove collaborators.